# What should our kids call grandpa's new wife?

Tags: step-parents, grandparents

Kids are 17 and 12.  Mom/grandma passed away a few year ago, and grandpa immediately married his new wife.  There is a long story there.  Dad/grandpa wants us to treat her as if she were grandma, but I have a hard time doing that.  My kids had a grandma that loved them so much.  New wife has no role whatsoever in kids life, other than showing up at family events 1-2 times per year.  She is not my mom, so why would she be the kids grandmother?  It is causing a conflict, and am hoping someone has a suggestion on what to call her, other than grandma or Miss "Kate".  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ultimately, this is a question that any blended family needs to answer for themselves -- this has been asked a few times before, I'll point you to that Q&A. I hope you find a resolution that respects everybody's feelings, I know it is difficult!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps some other name that implies familiarity and closeness, but has no actual meaning to your kids: mima, grammie, G-K (for Grandma Kate) come to mind. If culture/nationality is important to you and/or your kids and/or your dad and/or his new wife, perhaps a non-native language word for grandmother, e.g. I know of an American family that, in order to honor their Swedish heritage, refers to their grandmother as mormor. For them, it actually is a term of endearment, but for your kids, it could have its own special meaning.